# /dev/sda1 /boot is full

Tags: boot, ram, nginx

I know there are a lot of questions like this but I've tried pretty much to understand what to do and failed.

By `df -h` I know that my `/dev/sda1 /boot` is with 100% use.

I'm not understanding what I should remove, at all. I'm running nginx and wanted to install nodejs but I was alerted of unmet dependencies when trying `sudo apt-get install nodejs` and `sudo apt-get -f install` failed for lack of space. Can I get some specific guidance on this one please? I'm feeling totally lost.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image:

ii  linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic      3.8.0-29.42~precise1                 Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic      3.8.0-34.49~precise1                 Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic      3.8.0-35.52~precise1                 Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.8.0-36-generic      3.8.0-36.52~precise1                 Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.8.0-37-generic      3.8.0-37.53~precise1                 Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.8.0-38-generic      3.8.0-38.56~precise1                 Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.8.0-39-generic      3.8.0-39.58~precise1                 Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.8.0-42-generic      3.8.0-42.62~precise1                 Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic-lts-raring    3.8.0.44.44                          Generic Linux kernel image
```

> 

```
uname -r:
3.8.0-42-generic
```

> 

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-generic-lts-raring : Depends: linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

> 

```
sudo apt-get -f install

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic_3.8.0-44.66~precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during ./boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-44-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-44-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-44-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.8.0-44-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-44-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic_3.8.0-44.66~precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Probably you have many kernel versions installed. What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep -E 'linux-image|linux-headers'` and `df -h /boot`?

Comment: Well, that was in about the same *instant* as my answer below ;-)

Comment: Run the `dpkg -l ...` command from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu#100953)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/boot` contains (among other things) the linux kernels you have installed. These come with updates every now and then.

Open a Terminal and type
`dpkg --list | grep linux-image` and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

then compare the output from that with
`uname -r`
... where the output tells which of the above you have in use.

All the others can be removed, freeing up space - unless you have a reason to keep them. That is accomplished by replacing "linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic" here:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic
```

for each one that you wish to remove.

Then AFTER THE LAST - you MUST do this to clean up/recreate the boot menu accordingly

```
sudo update-initramfs -u                          # remakes boot ramdisk
sudo update-grub2                                 # re-creates boot menu
```

---

*edit*
This...

```
find /boot -type f -printf "%-16s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 20
```

... will show you the 20 largest files in /boot

Comment: thanks hannu, please check the edit to my answer, still in problems :s

Comment: As I said above `uname -r` tells what to keep. And then `replacing "linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic"` - means that you should take each of the others - `linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic` to `linux-image-3.8.0-39-generic` - and use them ONE AT A TIME instead of `linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic` in the sequence above. I've edited the above slightly to help you out a bit more.