# Ubuntu 16.04 package and space problem

Tags: 16.04, package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg

I initially received a notice of an error and to please run package manager to resole the issue. The error message was, error broken count > 0 and warned of installed packages having unmet dependencies.
(Note that I was not able to post Get:3, 4, 5,) I thank you very much in advance for your very much needed help.

```
sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cups-filters linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic
Suggested packages:
  antiword docx2txt fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
  linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-52-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cups-filters linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 1 to remove and 114 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 116 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic amd64 4.4.0-51.72 [19.2 MB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic amd64 4.4.0-51.72 [38.6 MB]

(Reading database ... 501080 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-52-generic (4.4.0-52.73) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-52-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-52-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-52-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-52-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-52-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_ptvcbr/lib/modules/4.4.0-52-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_ptvcbr/lib/modules/4.4.0-52-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-52-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-52-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-52-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Thanks again -muru but a no go. My package manager keeps giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all run  `apt-get autoremove`  after that run  `df -h`  to check your disk space if your free disk space is more than 500 mb then run   `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -f`  these command will resolve your issue.

**Run all the command as root user**

Comment: Yes exactly  running as root now and my disc space full.  Looking to free up space. /dev/sda1                     472M  465M     0 100% /boot Any thoughts

Comment: Thanks, still working at it taking suggestion from >.  [http://askubuntu.com/questions/502971/dev-sda1-boot-is-full](/dev/sda1 /boot is full [duplicate])

Comment: I have zero disc space and seemingly can not purge packages or increase disc space.