# /boot is 100% full, apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic won't work

Tags: boot, kernel, disk-usage

I have a `/boot` overload.
Tried to follow [/dev/sda1 /boot is full](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502971/dev-sda1-boot-is-full), but got stuck.

History:

```
df
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                     485360       0    485360   0% /dev
tmpfs                    100744   10824     89920  11% /run
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01  49011528 7513836  39300100  17% /
tmpfs                    503716       0    503716   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                    503716       0    503716   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                474730  466955         0 100% /boot

dpkg --list | grep linux-image

ii  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic       4.4.0-21.37                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic       4.4.0-59.80                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic       4.4.0-62.83                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic       4.4.0-63.84                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic       4.4.0-64.85                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic       4.4.0-66.87                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic       4.4.0-67.88                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic       4.4.0-70.91                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic       4.4.0-71.92                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic       4.4.0-72.93                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic 4.4.0-21.37                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic 4.4.0-59.80                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic 4.4.0-62.83                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic 4.4.0-63.84                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic 4.4.0-64.85                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic 4.4.0-66.87                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic 4.4.0-67.88                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic 4.4.0-70.91                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic 4.4.0-71.92                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic 4.4.0-72.93                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic 4.4.0-75.96                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                4.4.0.75.81                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

!!! wow, so much, how could this happen ?

And then:

```
uname -r
4.4.0-21-generic
```

Trials to purge unused images:

```
apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: apt queues actions, which requires space to work. Use dpkg to remove a kernel or two, freeing the overhead apt needs. Then use apt to clean up.

Comment: Please note that the output of 'uname -r' indicates that you are running on an older version of the kernel (4.4.0-21).  After you have freed a little space on '/boot', you should boot into a newer kernel and use 'sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Removing old kernels to free space in `/boot` partition

If your system is running using an *old kernel* (usually the newest kernel boots by default) you should boot from the newest kernel installed, which seems to be `linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic` in your case.

Select it from the GRUB menu (hold or repeatedly press <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot if GRUB doesn't show at all).

When you have booted from your newest kernel, first run `sudo apt-get -f install`, trying to fix the unmet dependencies issues, if it works go on with any of the first two method below; if it *fails* jump to *manual package purge*.

#### The *apt* way

Try to correctly manage the space issue with apt:

- Run `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove`, apt should correctly manage removing all old-kernels and related packages *if you haven't messed too much with it*.

#### Using *purge_old_kernels* from *byobu* package

If *the apt way* doesn't work or it doesn't remove enough space:

- Install **byobu** running `sudo apt install byobu`.
- Then run `sudo purge-old-kernels`, which should remove old kernels in a cleaner way than directly purging packages.

#### Manual package purge

If any oh the above worked:

- Purge the oldest (*not running*) kernel with `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic && sudo update-grub`.
- Reboot and boot from the newest kernel available.
- Run `sudo apt-get -f install`.
- Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.
- Reboot using your *newest kernel*.
- Clean older kernels, via *The apt way* and/or _purge_old_kernels_.

#### The *dpkg* way

As a last resort, you can try to do it in *the `dpkg` way* which isn't the safest.

- Run from your terminal *(running from your newest installed kernel)*:

  ```
  echo $(dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p') $(dpkg --list | grep linux-headers | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/q;p') | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
  ```

  Borrowed from [this response](https://askubuntu.com/a/254585/298047).
- Reboot your system and run `sudo apt-get -f install`
- Do a *full upgrade* with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.
- Reboot *if needed (new kernel¿?)* and go with *the apt way*: `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove`.
- Run `sudo purge_old_kernels`, command from `byoby` package if still remains any old kernel version (*in addition to the current and previous version which are always kept as a safety precaution*).

Comment: Hey, wow, many thanks for your advice, all of you!

Comment: I am trying: 
`apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove`

It gives:
[link](https://pastebin.com/CU7Q6iSG)

and /boot is still 100%

Boyu won't install :
[link](https://pastebin.com/dZY0YziE)

I stop moving from here, so that I avoid putting too much mess and you guys may suggest the next moves.

Thanks

Comment: @Manny I updated my answer with some _dirtier_ alternatives. Be careful and always remember to **keep a backup of your important data**.

Comment: Tks.
First command gives : https://pastebin.com/pL01FGDd
Looks like bad news (?)

Comment: @Manny What's your `sudo apt-get -f install` output¿?

Comment: Here it is : https://pastebin.com/1Msx9Qq2

Comment: I think you are still booting from your older kernel version 4.4.0-21, try to boot from a newer kernel first, maybe 4.4.0-72 and try to start from there, if you have no luck, it may be worth doing a fresh install...

Comment: Editing /boot/grub/grub.cfg ?
File starts with 
'### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi'
I'm sorry but I do not see where to edit and how :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58005/discussion-between-manny-and-dgonzalez).

Comment: Ok I've tried removing mannualy one image in /boot and gor 96% space.
Tks @user535733 
Then I tried back dgonzalez approach, still failing but a bit better.
https://pastebin.com/aD6EdRfK
I'm using a console form my laptop, with ssh connexion, holding shift to choose the image from grub display does not work : no grub display appears...

Comment: Got it !

I was most reluctant to removing content in /boot
But you can (and in that case must) remove images that are not booted on.

When this is done apt-get -f install and apt autoclean &&  apt autoremove perfectly do the job.

Thanks again for helping, folks.

Comment: @Manny I'm glad to read that you could avoid doing a fresh install! Keep on rocking!

Comment: Many many thanks, really. Precious are words when you are alone face to a machine :)

Answer (score 2):

If `/boot` is so full that `apt remove` doesn't work (`No space left on device`), just `rm` some files (`vmlinuz` or `initrd.img`) belonging to the kernels you want to remove to free up enough space so you can then properly `apt remove` the packages. Of couse, as always when running `rm` as root, be extra careful for typos, etc., but even if you accidentally `rm` a file from a kernel you didn't want to remove, a simple `apt install --reinstall` will fix it.

Contrary to a common misconception, there is absolutely no problem with doing that, as anybody could see if they actually tried it instead of just repeating things they have heard. (In particular, I often read that doing so would result in "broken packages". No, that's not what broken packages means.)