# /boot/ runs full but purging does not help

Tags: boot, apt, kernel

I already tried what is mentioned in [/boot is 100% full, apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic won't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910231/boot-is-100-full-apt-get-purge-linux-image-x-x-x-x-generic-wont-work) but it did not help.

The root cause seems to be that there are old kernels which are no longer recognised by apt /  purge-old-kernels

**sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux host 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**sudo purge-old-kernels**

```
No kernels are eligible for removal
```

**sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-7**

```
linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic  linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic
```

**sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**sudo apt-get -f purge linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But contents are still:

```
/boot dir
total 459M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4,0K Mai 19 07:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4,0K Mai  8 18:34 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Jul 13  2016 abi-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Okt 27  2016 abi-4.4.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Feb  1 20:39 abi-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Mär 22 17:11 abi-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Mär 24 16:20 abi-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Apr 20 14:02 abi-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Jul 13  2016 config-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Okt 27  2016 config-4.4.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Feb  1 20:39 config-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Mär 22 17:11 config-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Mär 24 16:20 config-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Apr 20 14:02 config-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  57K Dez 11 10:45 glxinfo.log
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1,0K Mai  8 18:35 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  38M Nov 11  2016 initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Dez 27 18:15 initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Dez 27 18:14 initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Feb 10 02:53 initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Feb 12 10:17 initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Feb 21 00:12 initrd.img-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Mär 28 06:45 initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Mär 30 08:32 initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Mai  8 18:35 initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Mai  8 18:35 initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,0K Dez 11 10:48 inxi.log
drwx------  2 root root  12K Nov 11  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Jän 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jän 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jän 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 3,7M Jul 13  2016 System.map-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,7M Okt 27  2016 System.map-4.4.0-47-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Feb  1 20:39 System.map-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Mär 22 17:11 System.map-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Mär 24 16:20 System.map-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Apr 20 14:02 System.map-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6,8M Nov 11  2016 vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Okt 27  2016 vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Feb  1 20:39 vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Mär 22 17:11 vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Mär 24 16:20 vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Apr 20 14:02 vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  54K Dez 11 10:44 Xorg.0.log
```

I found a **pretty dirty workaround** now by manually moving old kernels to another folder via "mv".

So my question is: How do I prevent such situation from happening again? How can I fix the unrecognised other kernel versions (like 4.4.0-31)?

**UPDATE:**

**apt-cache search linux-image | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs dpkg -l 2>&1 | grep ^ii**

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic       4.4.0-75.96  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic       4.4.0-77.98  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic       4.4.0-78.99  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic 4.4.0-75.96  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic 4.4.0-77.98  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 odpkg-query: no packages found matching linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic 4.4.0-78.99  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                4.4.0.78.84  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

**dir /boot/**

```
total 359M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4,0K Mai 19 07:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4,0K Mai 19 07:41 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Feb  1 20:39 abi-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Mär 22 17:11 abi-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Apr 20 14:02 abi-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Apr 27 20:24 abi-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Feb  1 20:39 config-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Mär 22 17:11 config-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Apr 20 14:02 config-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 186K Apr 27 20:24 config-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  57K Dez 11 10:45 glxinfo.log
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1,0K Mai 19 17:35 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Dez 27 18:14 initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Feb 10 02:53 initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Feb 12 10:17 initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Feb 21 00:12 initrd.img-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Mär 28 06:45 initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Mai 19 07:47 initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Mai 19 07:47 initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  39M Mai 19 07:47 initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,0K Dez 11 10:48 inxi.log
drwx------  2 root root  12K Nov 11  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Jän 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jän 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jän 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Feb  1 20:39 System.map-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Mär 22 17:11 System.map-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Apr 20 14:02 System.map-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Apr 27 20:24 System.map-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Feb  1 20:39 vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Mär 22 17:11 vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Apr 20 14:02 vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Apr 27 20:24 vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  54K Dez 11 10:44 Xorg.0.log
```

Does this mean I can manually remove the versions not found by dpkg?

Thanks!

Comment: The old kernels are not "unrecognised" but rather they were generated before the "new" behaviour of autoremove started deleting things from the /boot.
I would suggest rm instead of mv as you should not need more than three kernels ("current" , "previous" and maybe "known good").
Also, It also looks like you've removed the currently running kernel package? That's usually not a good idea. 
You should also remove the old kernel packages from your system using apt remove (linux-headers-whatever, linux-headers-whatever-generic, linux-image-whatever and linux-image-extra-whatever-generic)

Comment: Thanks for your answer:
I dont think I removed the current kernel - 4.4.0-75 is still installed.
One more question: How do I know which to remove and how should remove them? Just with "rm"? apt remove does not recognise them.

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` removes old kernels and packages no longer needed automatically. I usually run it a few days after installing a new kernel and encountering no problems.

Comment: In my case it does not (no idea why) - as you can see there are still kernels like 4.4.0-31 and they were not removed?!

Comment: I would remove all older kernels except 75 and 77 and then run sudo update-grub2. This will rebuild your boot menu as well.

Comment: Also, this will show you which kernel images you are running (apt-cache search linux-image | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs dpkg -l 2>&1 | grep ^ii) (taken from https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775771). You should get only 1 or 2 results.

Comment: My comment was mainly in reference to the last part of your question (...How do I prevent such situation from happening again...). I should have made that clear. Out of curiosity​, how big is your **/boot** partition.

Comment: Thanks for all your help:
sergtech - I executed the apt-cache search and got versions 75,77 and 78 as result
jarleih - thanks I will keep the autoclean in mind - my /boot/ was created by Ubuntu setup and is 472M

Comment: Please mark, if [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1678187) affects you.

Comment: It seems you have manually removed some files related to linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic which is installed according to dpkg, but e.g.  vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic is missing at /boot. What are some log files doing there?

Comment: Do you have dual boot system with two linuxes or have you installed one on top of other?

Comment: I did not remove files regarding 4.4.0-77 and I have no clue why logfiles (eg Xorg.0.log) are there.
And it is also no dual boot system - it is my homeserver which was setup with 16.04 so not even an upgrade from an older Ubuntu version.